# Using the Usercommand class for a button

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns

Im trying to add functionality to a button in a WPF using the MVVM pattern in C# but im not quite sure on how to do it via using the Viewmodel class.

I tried adding functionality via the MainWindow from my WPF but that'd be faithful to the pattern.
Furthermore i tried making a Usercommand class that implements ICommand but im not quite sure how it works.

Comment: have your considered using any mvvm toolkit/library? eg. https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples

Comment: how to do a button can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand (for  mvvm toolkit)

Comment: Please provide a small code sample to what has been tried.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have probably created 90% of the class already.
You'll need an action variable which will save your function later.

```
public class UserCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        private Action<object> action;

        public UserCommand(Action<object> action)
        {
            this.action = action;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter != null)
                action(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Then you'll need to go into your VMMainWindow class and use your UserCommand class by adding an instance in your constructor and make a getter/setter.

```
public class VMMainWindow
{
   
    private UserCommand userCommand;

    public VMMainWindow()
    {
        userCommand = new UserCommand(new Action<object>(YourFunction));
    }

    public UserCommand UserCommand { get => userCommand; set => userCommand = value; }
```

Then bind your UserCommand to your xaml code in your View/WPF

```
    <Button Command="{Binding UserCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding YourParameter}"/>
```